# Netty 4.0.27 channelRead not fired

Tags: java

I'm making a server and I just started on sockets with Netty 4.0.27. Previously I've only used 3.x, so I don't have a lot of experience with 4.x. But what I made so far doesn't work 100%.

In my entry point I got this:

```
NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener();
listener.start(30000);
```

The network listener class contains this:

```
public class NetworkListener {

    private final EventLoopGroup bossGroup;
    private final EventLoopGroup workerGroup;

    private final ServerBootstrap bootstrap;

    public NetworkListener() {
        this.bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        this.workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        this.bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        this.bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializerImpl())
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128) // (5)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)
    }

    public void start(int port) {
        try {
            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
            future.channel().closeFuture().sync();

            System.out.println("Network listener bound on port " + port);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    private static class ChannelInitializerImpl extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new NetworkHandler());
        }
    }
}
```

And my networkhandler class

```
public class NetworkHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        Session session = Environment.getSessionController().addSession(ctx);
        session.sendRaw("@@");
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {

    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        System.out.println(cause.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My sendraw function:

```
public void sendRaw(String data) {
    data = data + (char)TERMINATE_PACKET_CHAR;
    this.channel.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(data, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}
```

Basically, the channelActive event gets fired (I've tested it) and I should return data from the client if I send @@. But what happens is, when I send @@, nothing happens, the channelRead event isn't fired and no exception is thrown.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Also the following line isn't printed either

```
System.out.println("Network listener bound on port " + port);
```